# IC switching signals with different voltage levels

Tags: integrated-circuit, level-shifting

I am reading about ICs and wondering if there are some ICs (and how to differ those) that can do a task which I will describe below.

I have several digital outputs from Arduino. Those signals are maximum 5VDC. Each of DO need to power some specific load, which requires a higher voltage (ex 12VDC) and not more that 40mA current. I have seen that there are level shifting ICs (TTL -> CMOS), are those the ones I need?

I am looking at the IC4504 and I wonder will I achieve what I need if I:

- bring 12VDC to Vdd
- bring 5VDC to Vcc (always HIGH)
- bring 6VDC to SELECT (always HIGH)
- bring 5VDC to Ain (from Arduino DO)

Will the Aout have 12VDC?
Will I require some transistor for amplifying the output current, since it is only a few miliamps?

Or I got everything wrong? :)

Comment: What is the IC4504? What does Vdd and Vcc mean to you? What are SELECT, Ain, and Aout?

Comment: @DanLaks It is IC, like Texas instruments CD4504B. SELECT, Ain and Aout are the pins.

Comment: you wont get 40mA from its output

Answer (score 1):

You might not even need any ICs, a couple of transistors wired up like this might do the job

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR0WAA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Load is another input on another device, so I only need to supply 12VDC. I am aware I can do it using two N-channel and P-channel mosfets, but I was trying to understand ICs and if I can use one IC for several switchings.

Comment: A ULN2003 is an IC and it has 7 transistor pull down outputs, the arduino can even drive it directly and it'll handle a load of up to 50V

Comment: So, if I connect 7 DO from Arduino to this IC, what would be the voltage on each of the outputs? If those outputs are connected to 7 digital inputs on some other device, will they be able to provide 10V-30V, which is a requirement for inputs to become high?

Comment: the IC can only pull the inputs down to ground, adding a resistor to pull it back up should do the trick. Resistor from 10-30V to device input. ULN2003 from device input to ground. that should do it. Just be aware that the logic will be inverted, i.e. a high from the arduino will turn the ULN2003 on which will pull down your device's input down to ground, when the Arduino outputs a Low, the ULN2003 will be off and the resistor will pull the input up to the high voltage making it a HIGH

Comment: I am new to electronics, so just to confirm: direct supply (12VDC) -> Resistor (?Ohms) -> Device DI; IC DO -> Device DI. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep, that sounds right, as you said the inputs need a few tens of mA, I'd recommend a resistor of only a couple hundred ohms, I can't say exactly because I don't know what you're controlling, but maybe start with a 500ohm 1/2W, see what happens and go from there